# How do I hide warning messages that come from a specific command?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, files, gui

Basically, I want to open the current folder I'm in from terminal. I do `gnome-open .` from terminal and this opens the current folder I'm in.

In my `.bashrc`, I have a simple function called `open` that does this for me.

> function open() {
>       gnome-open . }

So I just call `open`, and it works. The only issue is that I get a bunch of warning messages when I do this?

> (nautilus:414): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **:
>   g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion
>   'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed
>
> (nautilus:414): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **:
>   g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion
>   'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed
>
> (nautilus:414): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen:
>   assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
>
> (nautilus:414): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer
>   instance
>
> (nautilus:414): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object:
>   assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

**I don't really care about the warning messages, I just don't want to see them in the terminal. How can I `hide` warning messages that come from calling open?**

> function open() {
>       gnome-open . [ignore all warnings, just do what your asked] }

Comment: Try adding `2>/dev/null` to the function. I don't know if it will work since I don't have gnome, but that is the universal "don't give me your sass" modifier.

Comment: You could redirect the standard error to `/dev/null`.

Comment: @Munir where did the 2 come from?

Comment: 2 is the file descriptor for standard error. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case anyone wanted to know, I simply changed my function to redirect the error stuff.

Now it becomes

```
function open() {

   gnome-open . &>/dev/null
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, `&>` redirects both stdout and stderr

Comment: Yes. Well really there was no stdout, just stderr in this case